# Laravel Import data into database with new inputted data and data from model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm sorry in advance for the tricky title but I'll try to explain it.
I have to make a scrape site for school. I want to make it that way so the admins can create categories and add names of websites. They can also set up scrape templates and link them to a certain website.
In that way, the admin can easily fill in a link, pick a website from where it should scrape and in which category the articles belong.

When the website is chosen, the website should automatically know on which paths it should crawl to retrieve a specific type of information.

However, I have no clue how I should set this up. I know how I can put new data from a form into a database, but how can I input information that does not come from an input, but from data that is already stored into a database?

This is how I gave it a try:

```
    public function scrape(Request $request, $id) 
    {
        $categories = Category::all();
        $websites = Website::all();
        try 
        {
            $article = Article::create([
                'url' => $request->input('url'),
                'EAN' => Template::where('website_id' == 'website_id')->('EAN'),
                'title' => $request->input('naam'),
                'content' => $request->input('descr'),
                'image' => $request->input('img'),
                'prijs' => $request->input('prijs'),
                'category_id' =>$request->input('category_id'),
                'website_id' => $request->input('website_id'),
            ]);
            return redirect()-> back();
        }   catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Try to fix `('website_id' == 'website_id')` with something like `('website_id', $website->id)`, but you must run through all websites first. So `Template::where('website_id' == 'website_id')->('EAN')` must be moved somewhere outside, then make other logic.

Comment: What if i put a for each loop around the whole form?